# Select php included html element with jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, dom

I'd like to select an included html element with jQuery. How can I achive this?

index.php

```
<?php
    <html>
        <head>
            ...
        </head>
        <body>
            include('file.php');
        </body>
    <html>
?>
```

file.php

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="test">test</div>';
?>
```

select.js

```
let a = $('.test');
console.log(a); // returns undefined
```

Comment: Make sure js-code runs after html element appears in DOM or on `document.ready` event.

Comment: in the DOM structure <div class="test">test</div> is displayed?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Yes it is in the DOM structure.

Comment: @u_mulder I already tried using document.ready but it didn't work :/

Comment: `<?php <html> ...` Umm....  Try putting the `<?php` before your PHP calls, and end it before you start your HTML again.  i.e., `<?php include('file.php'); ?>`.  The code ***shouldn't even execute*** as it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your script after the page has fully loaded.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
   let test = $('.test');
   console.log(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be organized as follows: `<?php Php.Code.Goes.Here ?>`.  This can be surrounded by HTML, for instance, `<b><?php print("HELLO!"); ?></b>`.  This will display: **HELLO!**

So...you see the problem then, with...

```
<?php
    <html>
        <head>
            ...
        </head>
        <body>
            include('file.php');
        </body>
    <html>
?>
```

The HTML is ***IN*** the PHP.  You want this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('file.php'); ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

This code, of course, shouldn't have executed at all, since `<?php <html>` isn't really valid PHP syntax.